# Why strlen() returns an unexpected value

Tags: c

I wrote a program that gets a string (password) and checks its validity,
the conditions for the string are:

1. At least one number
2. At least one upper case and one lower case letter
3. Must contain  6 elements

So I covered the most of the conditions, but then I got troubled with the third condition, I tried using `strlen()` but it returned a wrong value.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 6
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int passCheck(char password[]);

/*
main will ask the user to enter a password and then it will send it to 
passCheck, and check the return value, if the password is valid or not.
input: none
output: none
*/
int main()
{
    char password[MAX] = { 0 };
    printf("Enter a password: ");
    fgets(password, MAX, stdin);
    if(password[strlen(password)-1] = '\n') {password[strlen(password)-1] = 0;}
    if (passCheck(password) == TRUE)
    {
        printf("Valid");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Invalid");
    }
    return (0);
} 
/*
passCheck will take the password and will see if it's meeting the conditions
, then passCheck will return true(valid) or false(invalid).
input: password string
output: flag
*/
int passCheck(char password[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int flag = FALSE; // true(1) or false(0)
    int len = 0;
    int checkInt = 0; // checks if password has a digit
    int checkChar = 0;
    int copy = 0;

    for (i = 0; password[i]; i++)
    {   
        if (strlen(password) == MAX)
        {
            len = TRUE;
        }
        if (isdigit(password[i]))/*checks if the input is a number(0-9) or 
        a char (A-Z, a-z)
        */
        {       
            checkInt = TRUE;

        }
        if ((password[i] >= 'A' && password[i] <= 'Z') || (password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            checkChar = TRUE;
        }

        if (password[i] == password[i-1]) // checks if there is the same char/num in a row
        {
            copy = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            copy = FALSE;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n" , len,checkInt, checkChar,strlen(password));
    if (copy)
    {
        flag = FALSE;
    }
    else if (len && checkInt && checkChar)
    {
        flag = TRUE;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The `printf()` in the `passCheck()` function I used is for checking if the string meets the conditions, the output is working well, however `len` is not working and the `strlen()` function always returns 4 if the number is great than 4. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Remember that strings in C are really called *null-terminated byte strings*. If you want a string to contain at most six characters, it actually needs *seven* characters. Your six character, *plus the terminator*.

Comment: If your password has a length of 6 characters, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: `if(password[strlen(password)-1] = '\n')` -->>  `if(password[strlen(password)-1] == '\n') `

Comment: Greater than 4? How much greater?

Comment: So your problem is a combination of *two* issues: The size of the array, and the assignment in the `if` condition instead of checking for equality.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From 5 upwards.  There's the null, then the newline code zaps the byte before that, and since the maximum length was 6 including null, that means the newline assigned at position 4 is zapped with a null byte, leaving the string length at 4, regardless.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @SouravGhosh @EOF The linked question is not a duplicate as we do have the nul terminater here. With `fgets(password, MAX, stdin);` we get up to 5 characters + \0 and everything is fine with regard to nul termination.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't claim the terminator is missing, only that there's not enough space for it. But I agree that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: On the 1st iteration (`i==0`) this `.... == password[i-1]` invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define MAX 6
char password[MAX] = { 0 }; // The LONGEST your password can be is 5-characters + NULL Terminator (\0)

strlen(password); // will never return anything more than 5.
```

If you want your password to be 6 characters, the buffer has to be 7-characters:

- 6 for the password
- 1 for the end-of-string marker: `\0`

Comment: And if the password is longer, the extra characters plus the newline will be left in the buffer.  It would be more sensible to use a buffer size of, oh, 128 or 4096, to make sure the whole line is read, then drop the newline, then worry about the length of the password.